# Multi-mapping to the same table twice

Tags: dapper

How do you use Dapper's Multi-Mapping feature on two fields using the same table? i.e `ClientInfo` has two `Address` objects.

```
public class ClientInfo
{
    public Guid Id => Guid.NewGuid();
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address PostalAddress { get; set; }
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; } 
    public int ContactNumber { get; set; }        
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string FirstLine { get; set; }
    public string SecondLine { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

## Tables

Relational - Address.Id used in ClientInfo.PostalAddress / BillingAddress

```
tbl.Address
|Id|FirstLine|SecondLine|Town|PostCode    

tbl.ClientInfo
|Id|FirstName|LastName|PostalAddress|BillingAddress|etc..
```

## Current implementation

Results only in all but **PostalAddress** being mapped.

```
var sql = @"select * from ClientInfo c left join Address as a on a.Id = c.PostalAddress left join Address as ad on ad.Id = c.BillingAddress";

var clients = connection.Query<ClientInfo, Address, Address, ClientInfo>(
                    sql,
                    (client, postal, billing) =>
                    {
                        client.PostalAddress = postal;
                        client.BillingAddress = billing;
                        return client;
                    },
                    splitOn: "PostalAddress,BillingAddress")
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

return clients;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `splitOn` parameter tells Dapper when/where to start mapping the next object, so you need to ensure that your SQL query returns the information in the correct order. Right now, you return 2 guids for PostalAddress and BillingAddress. Dapper doesn't know how to map them both.

`select * from ... join ...` will result in the `Address` data ordered AFTER the `ClientInfo.PostalAddress` and `ClientInfo.BillingAddress` columns.

Try: `SELECT c.Id, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.ContactNumber, a.*, ad.* FROM ClientInfo c LEFT JOIN Address AS a ON a.Id = c.PostalAddress JOIN Address AS ad ON ad.Id = c.BillingAddress`

As you can see, removing the `*` effectively excludes the `PostalAddress` and `BillingAddress` guids from the results and we can now now `splitOn: "Id,Id"`.

Answer (score -1):

You will of course not have to provide the GUIDs in the select statement, this is just for the test to work.

```
[Test]
public void TestAbcd()
{
    using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        const string sql = @"WITH ClientInfo AS (

                                 SELECT * FROM (
                                     VALUES (@ci1, @adr1, @adr2), (@ci1, @adr3, @adr4)
                                     ) AS a (Id, PostalAddress, BillingAddress)
                             ),

                             Address AS (

                                 SELECT * FROM (
                                     VALUES
                                         (@adr1), (@adr2), (@adr3), (@adr4)
                                     ) AS a (Id)

                             )

                             select * from ClientInfo c left join Address as a on a.Id = c.PostalAddress left join Address as ad on ad.Id = c.BillingAddress";

        dbConnection.Open();

        var clients = dbConnection.Query<ClientInfo, Address, Address, ClientInfo>(
                sql,
                (client, postal, billing) =>
                {
                    client.PostalAddress = postal;
                    client.BillingAddress = billing;
                    return client;
                },
                splitOn: "PostalAddress,BillingAddress",  param: new {
                    ci1 = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    ci2 = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    adr1 = Guid.NewGuid(), 
                    adr2 = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    adr3 = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    adr4 = Guid.NewGuid()
                })
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both either removing or changing the split results in: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'WorkAssignTest.Address'.'

Comment: The SQL is incorrect, you need to ensure results are in the correct order so that you can splitOn correctly.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my previous answer. Please see above working test